# libcanberra is failing to build

Tags: compiling

I got version 0.26 from [libcanberra site](http://0pointer.de/lennart/projects/libcanberra/), and running `make` gives:

```
make[2]: *** No rule to make target `README', needed by `all-am'.  Stop.
make[2]: Leaving directory `/home/wena/src/gnome/libcanberra-0.26/doc'
make[1]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/wena/src/gnome/libcanberra-0.26'
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

Output of `./configure`:

```
prefix:                 /usr/local
sysconfdir:             ${prefix}/etc
localstatedir:          ${prefix}/var
Compiler:               gcc -std=gnu99
CFLAGS:                 -g -O2 -Wall -W -Wextra -pedantic -pipe -Wno-long-long -Winline -Wvla -Wno-overlength-strings -Wunsafe-loop-optimizations -Wundef -Wformat=2 -Wlogical-op -Wsign-compare -Wpacked -Wformat-security -Wmissing-include-dirs -Wformat-nonliteral -Wold-style-definition -Wpointer-arith -Winit-self -Wdeclaration-after-statement -Wfloat-equal -Wmissing-declarations -Wmissing-prototypes -Wstrict-prototypes -Wredundant-decls -Wmissing-noreturn -Wshadow -Wendif-labels -Wstrict-aliasing=2 -Wcast-align -Wwrite-strings -Wno-unused-parameter -ffast-math -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fno-common -fdiagnostics-show-option -fno-strict-aliasing
C++-Compiler:           g++
CXXFLAGS:               -g -O2
Builtin DSO:            yes
Enable PulseAudio:      yes
Builtin PulseAudio:     no
Enable ALSA:            yes
Builtin ALSA:           no
Enable OSS:             yes
Builtin OSS:            no
Enable GStreamer:       yes
Builtin GStreamer:      no
Enable Null Output:     yes
Builtin Null Output:    no
Enable tdb:             no
Enable lookup cache:    no
Enable GTK+:            yes
GTK Modules Directory:  ${exec_prefix}/lib/gtk-2.0/modules
Enable GTK3+:           yes
GTK3 Modules Directory: ${exec_prefix}/lib/gtk-3.0/modules
```

**UPDATE**: I'm no longer experiencing this problem and have no idea what fixed it.

Comment: @Tshepang: Show us what make command you ran (`make all-am`?) and the full output from that command. And put a link to the source you downloaded.

Comment: @Gilles: `make all` IMHO juging on last lines.

Comment: @Tshepang: maybe mark this one as answered so it doesn't keep popping up?

Comment: @FaheemMitha: even if the Answer didn't work?

Comment: @Tshepang: Add your own answer, then accept it. "No longer experiencing" qualifies as an answer, I think. Another option would be to simply remove the question.

Comment: @FaheemMitha: As mentioned in the update to my post, I have no idea what fixed it.

Comment: @Tshepang: Yes, I'm aware of that. Perhaps there should be some category for unanswerable questions, but since there isn't, I'm suggesting you add a "dummy" answer, and accept it.

Comment: @FaheemMitha: I've never heard of the scheme you are suggesting. It does make sense, but is it used elsewhere? Would you like to ask on Meta about that scheme, *Do we leave posts Unanswered if the questioner has moved on*?

Comment: @Tshepang: Sure, you could ask on Meta. Maybe there is some policy.

Answer (score 1):

You're probably missing the [GTK-Doc](http://www.gtk.org/gtk-doc/) tools to generate documentation.

One way to find out these dependencies by looking at what distributions do to build the package. For example on [Debian](http://packages.debian.org/sid/libcanberra0), in [`debian/control`](http://ftp.de.debian.org/debian/pool/main/libc/libcanberra/libcanberra_0.24-1.diff.gz), the dependencies (except Debian-specific stuff) are

> m4, libltdl-dev | libltdl7-dev (>= 2.2.6), libasound2-dev, libvorbis-dev, libgtk2.0-dev (>= 2.20), tdb-dev (> 1.1), gtk-doc-tools, libpulse-dev (>= 0.9.11), libgstreamer0.10-dev (>= 0.10.15)

Comment: The command for that is `apt-get build-dep libcanberra`. Anyways, I did run it and still got the same problem. BTW my problem got fixed later on by... who knows. I wish I could pinpoint what the trouble was :(